# Are there any statements in Mahabharata that confirm that the shape of earth is not flat?

Tags: mahabharata, science, earth

It is well known that several scriptures in Hinduism declare that the shape of earth is not flat.

So Hindu scriptures refute the idea of a flat earth.

***Are there any statements explicitly from Mahabharata stating that earth is not flat?***

**Note** that I am not asking for the exact shape of earth from any scripture. I am asking for statements only from Mahabharata that refute the flat shape concept of earth.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**.

There is a statement in Mahabharata that refutes the idea that earth is flat in shape.

The bold portion of the following conversation between Vyasa and Kunti confirms that earth is not a flat body.

> 'Vaisampayana continued, 'Vyasa, the son of Satyavati, thus comforting
>   the Pandavas, led them into the town of Ekachakra. And the master also
>   comforted Kunti, saying, 'Live, O daughter! This son of thine,
>   Yudhishthira, ever devoted to truth, this illustrious bull among men,
>   having by his justice conquered the whole world, will rule over all
>   the other monarchs of the earth. There is no little doubt that, having
>   by means of Bhima's and Arjuna's prowess conquered the **whole earth
>   with her *belt* of seas**, he will enjoy the sovereignty thereof. Thy
>   sons as well as those of Madri--mighty car-warriors all--will
>   cheerfully sport as pleaseth them in their dominions. These tigers
>   among men will also perform various sacrifices, such as the Rajasuya
>   and the horse-sacrifice, in which the presents unto the Brahmanas are
>   very large. And these thy sons will rule their ancestral kingdom,
>   maintaining their friends and relatives in luxury and affluence and
>   happiness.'
>
> [[SECTION CLVIII, Hidimva-vadha Parva, Adi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01159.htm)

Vyasa, while describing the earth, told that the earth contains seas as its *belt*. Thus, conforming that earth is not flat.

Comment: Not sure how this conveys that earth is not flat? Also what is the sanskrit text?

Comment: @PrakashK  मेखला  http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?tran_input=mekhalA&direct=se&script=hk&link=yes&mode=3 is the word used in Sanskrit, which means belt/ gridle/ wasit-band. It is used for non-flat surfaces only (especially spheres).

Comment: It also is used to denote boundaries, not necessarily non-flat surfaces. like vedi-mekhalA which means boundary of the sacrifical altar (vedi). So all i am saying is that, its not conclusive.

Comment: @PrakashK please provide a link for that meaning.

Comment: http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=mekhalA&lang=sans&iencoding=itrans&action=Search  This has various meaning of mekhalA including the meaning i quoted as used in Srimad Bhagavatam as well.

Comment: @PrakashK if we take the majority of the meaning as well as experts in other language translations such as Telugu also includes waist-band. Even if we take your argument as a boundary. How can we interpret it? **Whole** Earth with seas as it's boundary! Which means flag Earth surrounded by seas! Is it?

Comment: Well, it can be interpreted that way. :-) unless ofcourse there is some shastric-nyaya which makes it clear that this cannot be used for flat surface boundary.

Comment: Telugu poets usually describe the earth as Brahmanda Aakaram, to be in shape of a humongous egg. It is mentioned in Vedas.

Comment: In my view based on how a belt or girdle is used, it is round when it says surrounded by oceans/seas. You wrap a belt around an object. While it may not be a sphere necessarily it isn't flat.